# Give a counterexample disproving: $Boundary(Closure(A)) = Boundary(A)$

Tags: general-topology

I know that for set $A$, Closure($A$) = $A \cup L$ where $L$ is the set of limit points.

So $Boundary(A \cup L) = Boundary(A) $

It doesn't seem like it's true necessarily I just cannot give a concrete example.

Could anyone give an example showing A and it's closure, and its set of limit points please.

Comment: What is your definition of the boundary of a set?

Comment: You would need for the interior of $\overline{A}$ to be bigger than the interior of $A$. You can obtain this if you have holes that are filled in the closure.

Comment: @SantanaAfton -- My definition of the boundary of $A$ is the set of all points $P$ for which any open set $S\ni P$ contains some point in $A$ and some point not in $A$. An interior point has some open set $S\ni P$ containing only points in $A$. An exterior point has some open set $S\ni P$ containing only points not in $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = \mathbb{Q}$ in the reals, usual topology.

its closure is $\mathbb{R}$ which has empty boundary.

its boundary is $\mathbb{R}$ which is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

How about a punctured disk?

Its closure is the whole disk, which has boundary a circle.

But the punctured disk's boundary is the circle along with the point in the middle.

Comment: I'm actually taking an intro to real analysis course, not a topological class. How could we represent a punctured disk in terms of a set?

Comment: $A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid0<x^2+y^2<1\}$

Comment: $\overline A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ , $\text{bd}(\overline A)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ , $\text{bd}(A)=\text{bd}(\overline A)\cup\{(0,0)\}$